# import JSON file to google firestore using cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to GCP and Python. I have got a task to import JSON file into google firestore using google cloud functions via Python.

Kindly assist please.

Comment: I'm sure some of the pieces you need are already available somewhere. What have you found and what exactly are you missing?

Comment: @MarCialR, Actually I'm new to GCP and python as well. So, couldn't understand the actual code to be written to perform the import via cloud functions.

Comment: What's the size of your file? What is the format of your file? Is it only one JSON document, that you want to load into firestore (only one document)? Or do you want to split this unique document? Or your file contain 1 json document per line (JSONL format)? Tell us more!

Answer (score 2):

I could achieve this system setup using below code. Posting for your reference:-

## **CLOUD FUNCTIONS CODE**

### *REQUIREMENTS.TXT (Dependencies)*

```
`google-api-python-client==1.7.11
google-auth==1.6.3
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-cloud-storage==1.19.1
google-cloud-firestore==1.6.2`
```

## *MAIN.PY*

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import firestore
import json

client = storage.Client()``

def hello_gcs_generic(data, context):

print('Bucket: {}'.format(data['bucket']))
print('File: {}'.format(data['name']))

bucketValue = data['bucket']
filename = data['name']
print('bucketValue : ',bucketValue)
print('filename : ',filename)

testFile = client.get_bucket(data['bucket']).blob(data['name'])
dataValue = json.loads(testFile.download_as_string(client=None))
print(dataValue)

db = firestore.Client()

doc_ref = db.collection(u'collectionName').document(u'documentName')
doc_ref.set(dataValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud functinos are server less functions provided by google. The beauty of cloud function is it will destroy it will invoke any trigger happens and itself once the execution is complete. Cloud functions are single purpose functions. Not only python, you can also use NodeJS and Go to write cloud functions. You can create a cloud function very easily by visiting quick start of cloud functions (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console).

Your task is to import a JSON file into google firestore. This part you can do using Firestore python connector like any normal python program and add into cloud function console or upload via gcloud. Still the trigger part is missing here. As I mentioned cloud function is serverless. It will execute when any event happens in the attached trigger. You haven't mentioned any trigger here (when you want to trigger the function). Once you give information about the trigger I can give more insights on resolution.

Comment: thanks for the details. trigger point is JSON file upload in cloud bucket. Can you plz assist me with code to connect firestore via python and place it in cloud functions. I have reached till triggering the cloud function on cloud bucket trigger, then reading the JSON file. Now the task is to connect firestore and dump the JSON data into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ishank Aggarwal, You can add the above code snippet as a part of cloud function by following steps:

1. https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/
2. Create function using function name, yours requirements, choose run time as python and choose trigger as your gcs bucket.

Once you create it, if any change happens in your bucket, the function will trigger and execute your code